# Messaging System - MySql / PHP / Kohana

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I am developing a messaging system using the following structure in the database.

[image: I took the diagram here on the site]

The question is how to select all messages in PHP grouping by user.

EX:

-All messages from user A to user X

-All messages from user B to user X

-All messages from user C to user X

(user X = user logged)

Comment: I think you mean "sorted" and not "grouped" by user, right ?

Comment: What does `user_id` in the `users_has_messages` table mean?  How do you know the "from" and "to" for each message?  Do you have more tables or more fields?

Comment: it is grouped. The logged User has he see all the conversations he had. equal in the messages facebook

Comment: something is wrong in the schema. How do you know the "From" or the "To" of a message ?

Comment: the table (users_has_messages) contains all users that have the conversation. 

the table (messages) has a field (from_id).

Comment: @VitorDeco: But how do you differentiate between "to" and "from"?

Comment: that information (from_id) is essential for the answer ! I based my answer on that, and the kohana tag (assuming you use at least the 3.1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all required informations are in tables, here is a partial solution that uses the database module of kohana3. If the following doesn't fit your schema, you will easily adapt it.

```
$user_id = '1'; // whatever how you get the current user
$messages = DB::select('*')->from('messages')
  ->join('users_has_messages', 'LEFT')->on('messages_id', '=', 'id')
  ->where('users_id', '=', $user_id)
  ->order_by('from_id ASC')
  ->execute()->as_array();
foreach($messages as $msg)
{
  echo $msg->id.':'.$msg->subject.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Ok, listed all my messages, I had arrived here using Kohana ORM. thank you! 

What is difficult is to display only the last message of each conversation, grouping by user. as in facebook chat on the left side my last conversations with that person appears.

Comment: to display only the last message, you can combine `order_by()` with `limit(1)`. This works for Database_Query_Builder object, and also probably for ORM

Answer (score 1):

You could easily grab all messages with a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT messages.* FROM users
JOIN users_has_messages ON users.id = users_has_messages.users_id
JOIN messages ON users_has_messages.messages_id = messages.id
WHERE users.id = __THE ID OF THE USER__
```

Just replace `__THE ID OF THE USER__` with the id of the user you are interested in getting messages from.

The way this query works is by 'joining' the tables together 'on' certain conditions. First we join the `users` table to the `users_has_messages` table when `users.id = users_has_messages.users_id` then we do a similar 'join' to the `messages` table.

Finally you use the `WHERE` statement to define conditions. In this case, we only want the users with a specific id.

After looking at your last edit, it seems you want to get all the messages *from* a particular user as well. Unfortunately, your schema doesn't have the information of who sent the message. If you want that, you will have to add the `send_user_id` to the `messages` table. Then you could do this:

```
SELECT messages.* FROM users
JOIN users_has_messages ON users.id = users_has_messages.users_id
JOIN messages ON users_has_messages.messages_id = messages.id
WHERE users.id = __THE ID OF THE RECIEVER__
AND messages.send_user_id = __THE ID OF THE SENDER__
```